# Help needed with deleting a Ubuntu partition

Tags: 12.04, 13.04, dual-boot, partitioning

I have a question about my partitioning. 
Some months ago my laptop crashed, so I decided to put Ubuntu on it. 
Because I had some experience with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS I choose to create a dual-boot with Ubuntu 12.04 and Ubuntu 13.04.

Since I never use Ubuntu 13.04 and my Ubuntu 12.04 partition is running out of memory I want to delete the 13.04 partition.

I am a newbie with these things, so I hoped you guys could help me out.
How can I delete the 13.04 partition without losing data from my 12.04 partition?

A screenshot of Gparted:

[image]

How can I see which partition contains which Ubuntu version? 
And what about the swap partition?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can differentiate them by size. Boot into your 12.04 and check the properties of `/`. There is a 30Gb size difference between the two `ext4` partitions.

Comment: Did it, turns out that 12.04 is located on dev/sda2. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make a educated guess here. If you never used ubuntu 13.10, I am assuming it is your /dev/sda1. My reasoning

- Base installation is short of 8GB, if you never used it, the disk usage makes sense
- /dev/sda2 has more of occupied space, which is why you want more space
- If you are not using 13.10, there would be no key (locked) next to the partition name

I'm pretty sure /dev/sda1 is 13.10. Otherwise, it would be mounted.

To double check, `df` will show what partitions are mounted. If you are still not sure, boot into 13.10 and see what is mounted with `df` or gparted.

What you would need to do is format the /dev/sda1 partition to make more space. Unfortunately you will not be able to extend your 12.04 partition to the new free space. What you can do though is mount it when you use 12.04 and it will act as an "external" harddrive. If this bothers you, you can mount this automatically via scripts on startup.

**WARNING**

Simply formatting your 13.10 partition will mess up your bootloader because the bootloader is located on the same partition. You need to reinstall the bootloader in the /dev/sda2, or /dev/sda1 (one suggestions is to make a new /boot partition of ~300mb) after formatting it. [Here is a tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition)

Comment: Thanks for your information. I figured out that the 12.04 is indeed located on /dev/sda2. Does someone has a advice how I could backup my complete 12.04 (with userdata, software and settings), and then format my complete harddisk and install Ubuntu 12.04 with all my previous settings?